# What is the best way for constructing a never matching `Pattern`?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

An existing interface requires a `Pattern` instance for matching labeled items, but I want to ignore all items at some point. `Pattern` has no constant `NO_MATCH`, `DISCARD_ALL` or something similar.

Currently I use this:

```
Pattern.compile("^.^")
```

Is there a better solution?

(PS, sadly, java's regex engine lacks support for backtracking controls like `(*FAIL)`.)

Comment: Actually, `(?!)` acts as `(*FAIL)`, it is used in constructions like `(*SKIP)(?!)`, as a synonym of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for this information. To the duplication flag: I have seen the previous question, but my question is java related; so, for example, I would be very happy a dedicated `Pattern` instance for unmatching.

Comment: Use `(?!)` and it will never match anything.